# In JavaScript is it possible on IE to register one event listener to capture all the change, focus, and blur events on the page?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, setfocus

- In non-IE browsers:

  - The `change` event bubbles, so you can catch it when it gets to `document` in the bubbling phase.
  - The `focus` and `blur` events don't bubble, but you can catch them on the capture phase with one event listener on `document`.
- On IE:

  - None of those 3 events bubble (including the `change` event, which is not spec compliant).
  - There is no capture phase on IE.

So, as far as I know, the only way on IE is to register an event listener for `change`, `focus`, and `blur` on every form control. This operation can be expensive when you have a lot of controls. But is there a better way?

Comment: FYI, re: `focus` and `blur` not bubbling, IE gives you `focusin` and `focusout` (respectively), which do bubble and can be reliably swapped in. See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

Comment: And there won't be a `change` event on an `input` element without a prior `focusin` event. So on IE you could listen for `focusin` and then attach `change` event handlers directly to the event target. I assume this is how libraries fake it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.4 defines 'focusin' and 'focusout' to capture focus and blur events for all browsers.

Comment: 1.4 also fakes out a `change` event that "bubbles".